# How can I fix "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" while accessing data?

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, windows-8

On the selection changed event I am accessing the data from one of my tables. But the "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" is thrown.

```
var query = conn.Table<auto_fares>().Where(x => x.city == cbCity.SelectedItem);
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    txtDistance.Text = item.min_km.ToString();
    lblDayFare.Text = item.min_fare.ToString();
    lblNightFare.Text = item.night_charges.ToString();
}
```

After adding the Dispose statement i am getting the following error as 
"The await operator can only be used within an async lamhda expression. Consider making this lamhda expression with the 'async' modifier."

How can I solve this?

Comment: Look at the InnerException - that will show you what's *actually* happened.

Comment: Can you give the details of the exception...

Comment: I am not able to get the inner exception as it is thrown from the SQLite.cs file which is an inbuilt file for SQLite access in windows 8 app development. Please guide.

Comment: The inner exception is : {"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-writing your code like this:

```
var selectedCity = cbCity.SelectedItem;
var query = conn.Table<auto_fares>().Where(x => x.city == selectedCity);
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    txtDistance.Text = item.min_km.ToString();
    lblDayFare.Text = item.min_fare.ToString();
    lblNightFare.Text = item.night_charges.ToString();
}
```

You're trying to access a UI component (cbCity.SelectedItem) from a non-UI thread (await query.ToListAsync() )

Answer (score 0):

This foreach is executed asynchronously and you are accessing your UI from a different thread. Wrap your foreach in a Dispatcher.Invoke().

Like so:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke( new Action( () => {... your foreach...}   );
```

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to explain @h.alex. Can you please give me a block of code. Thanks again.

Comment: If this doesn't work in exactly this form, then pick either of your controls, or better yet, the window they are on and use it's Dispatcher instead of the current one. U're welcome.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks to me like it's `cbCity.SelectedItem` which is being accessed on the wrong thread.  None of the code he's posted suggests the `foreach` is operating on a different thread?

Comment: @h.alex : How can I do that i.e getting the thread for the controls? I am badly stuck. :(

Comment: yeah,yeah u are right. actually the foreach as i understand the new await keyword from a bit of googling would get executed as a continuation of the async action. but maybe they made id run on the ui thread by default so this is why it doesn't crash.